# fixed point for sine approx

Tags: point, fixed

I want to implement the fixed point sine /cosine wave generator. My input is angle theta (varies from -1 to +1) and I need output of sine/cosine to be also in the range (-1 to 1). So that entire model can be configured in Q15 format. Could anybody help me with this.

P.S: I need trig approx for full 4 quadrants

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? Please share your attempts, and tag the programming language you are using

Comment: I would appreciate if you can provide C code for my above specifications

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also contain your attempts to resolve the problem on your own